# Wifi not connecting on Debian 9

Tags: debian, wifi

I burned a live iso image of debian 9 gnome i386 and booted it from my usb.   Everything worked perfectly, but it was not finding any local wifi.

After reading that the free version was missing the necessary firmware, I burned the debian 9 gnome i386 with non-free firmware and booted from my usb.  This time my wifi was found, but when I entered my password it tried to connect for a few seconds and then disconnected.

I'm not sure what to do from here.  There is no problem with the network or password, as I was able to login and use the internet from the PC I am using now.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the output of: lspci  What is the output of: lsusb

Comment: Did `wpasupplicant` somehow go missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar problems when installing Debian Jessie (8) and upgrading to Stretch (9). To specify arochester's comment you are interested in Network's position in lspci:

```
lspci | grep Network
```

For example, for me it is:

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
```

Intel hardware requires firmware. During fresh install, usually I burn standard Debian iso image on usb pen-drive and provide the firmware (for me from: [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html)) with the same usb stick. Then I follow README :)
I also reacall that [firmware-iwlwifi](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-iwlwifi) package is required for this manual installation. More insights (power-saving, etc.) you can find [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/638554).

I would strongly suggest to give Ubuntu (Live USB) a try. From my experience it is easier to obtain a wifi connection with it (for various wifi cards). It can clarify some potential issues.

Did you use GUI Network Manager? It is a good idea to use command-line interface to establish a connection (if you haven't done it already). It provides better output in case something goes wrong ([How to connect to wifi via command line](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-connect-to-a-wpa-wifi-using-command-lines-on-debian)). Personally, I'd recommend wifi-menu command (part of netctl; it works on Arch linux, I'm not sure if it works on Debian too).

Good luck with your problem and have a nice day :)

Regards,
Mikolaj

EDIT*
See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250143/258734) great answer by Rui F Ribeiro.